# Should I expect wall texture spray can to be usable a second time?

Tags: walls

I'm on my third can of spray texture, this time from Homax.  Each works the first time, I clear the nozzle before I store.... then nothing.
Are these one time use products? Or can I use them again for wall repairs (i.e., nail hole in the wall, etc.).

How do I clear the can? Now I have three different brands, all used once, and none working now.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that these are, generally speaking, one use products.

You can improve your odds by turning them in a way that blows propellant (usually down, but some products are tricky that way) and clears the airway, but even this is hit and miss. (Among other things, it gives you less propellant for the next time, so you'll end up with goo in the can that you can't shoot.)

So buy small cans if you have a small job.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I made the mistake of buying the bigger "contractor grade" this time and its oil based... clogged can.  Called the company, they said put it in a sink of hot water for about 5 mins.  Didn't work... Guess I'm going to buy another can.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on: actually the can now works fine. More soaking of it without the nozzle attached. I will remove and clean the nozzle afterward and run hot water down into the hole into the can. Then I will not reinsert the nozzle until next use.

Homax could put this on the label.

Answer (score 0):

After much effort because I am cheap... if using the small aerosol can, pull nozzle out and use a needle or paper clip and water to remove the clog, working from both ends. Flush with water until it runs out freely. The outlet of the can itself was also clogged--the point where the piping descends from the nozzle and fits into the can. I pounded a needle into the clog and let it soak, and repeated. I eventually got enough of the texture to come out that I did my four-inch square job. But it was a huge pain.

Homax needs to give readers a guide to cleaning things out after each use.